# ios barButtonItem moving

Tags: ios, image, navigationbar

For some reason when I switch to another tab and switch back to my original tab, the right barButtonItem image moves. It's suppose to be like this: 
[image] 
But when I go back to the screen it looks like this:
[image]
I'm not editing the button at all anywhere. The location where the button responds is still correct, just the image is not in the right place. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post code that creates the button?

Comment: I don't actually use code to create it. I added it via the story board, which is why I'm even more puzzled as to why this is happening.

Comment: Well, that is even more strange. How do you switch between the view controllers?

Comment: Sorry I think I've been unclear. My navigation controller is in a tab bar controller, so I meant when I click on another tab and then go back to this tab. This button plays no part in that switching, as it does something else. But in the scenario I described, I don't press the button at all.